# Rebase csv file by merging a base csv file with another new csv file

Tags: python, csv, python-2.x

I am currently working with two csv files, base.csv and another csv file, output_20170503.csv which will be produced everyday, so my aim here is to rebase every output so that they have the same data as the base.csv.

My base.csv:

```
ID,Name,Number,Shape,Sound
1,John,45,Round,Meow
2,Jimmy,78,Sphere,Woof
3,Marc,,Triangle,Quack
4,Yun,50,Triangle,Meow
5,Nyancat,,Round,Quack
```

My output_20170503.csv

```
ID,Name,Number,Shape,Sound
1,John,,Round,Meow
2,Jimmy,,Sphere,Woof
3,Marc,,Triangle,Quack
4,Yun,,Triangle,
5,Nyancat,,Round,Quack
6,Marc,,Square,Woof
7,Jonnn,,Hexagon,Chirp
```

The objective here is to rebase the data (ID from 1-5) from base.csv with the output_20170503.csv

What I want to achieve:

```
ID,Name,Number,Shape,Sound
1,John,45,Round,Meow
2,Jimmy,78,Sphere,Woof
3,Marc,,Triangle,Quack
4,Yun,50,Triangle,Meow
5,Nyancat,,Round,Quack
6,Marc,,Square,Woof
7,Jonnn,,Hexagon,Chirp
```

I already searched for the solution but what I got;

> Merge two csv files (both of csv files have different columns, won't work for me)
>
> Remove duplicates from a csv files (Appending base.csv with the output_20170503.csv and then remove the duplicates, won't work because they have different values for column Number)

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: How did ID=4 get empty Number but ID=5 get Number=50?

Comment: @agamagarwal Sorry, it was a typo, changed it. Thank you for noticing

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, I use first two item as key and generate a dict and then iterate the `new` dict update the `base` dict if the key not in `base`:

```
new = {"".join(i.split(',')[:2]): i[:-1].split(',') for i in open('output_20170503.csv')}
base = {"".join(i.split(',')[:2]): i[:-1].split(',') for i in open('base.csv')}

base.update({i: new[i] for i in new if i not in base})
f=open("out.csv","w")
for i in sorted(base.values(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    if i[0]!="ID":
        f.write(",".join(i)+"\n")
```

Output:

```
1,John,45,Round,Meow
2,Jimmy,78,Sphere,Woof
3,Marc,,Triangle,Quack
4,Yun,50,Triangle,Meow
5,Nyancat,,Round,Quac
6,Marc,,Square,Woof
7,Jonnn,,Hexagon,Chir
```

---

**Python2.7+** supports the syntactical extension called the "dictionary comprehension" or "dict comprehension", so if you're using Python2.6, you need to replace the first three lines with:

```
new = dict(("".join(i.split(',')[:2]),i[:-1].split(',')) for i in open('output_20170503.csv'))
base = dict(("".join(i.split(',')[:2]),i[:-1].split(',')) for i in open('base.csv'))

base.update(dict((i,new[i]) for i in new if i not in base))
```

Comment: I got syntax error on the for loop , btw, I'm using python v2.6.. `new = {"".join(i.split(';')[:1]): i[:-1].split(';') for i in open(new_devicedb)}`

Comment: Thank you, but the base update also has Syntax Error at the for loop. `base.update({i: new[i] for i in new if i not in base})` Do I need to import any library?

Comment: @yunaranyancat Update.

Comment: By changing the ',' to ';', would it be the same if the values were semicolon  delimited?

Comment: @yunaranyancat sure

Comment: Last question, if I want to use only the first column of the file, I need to change from `new = {"".join(i.split(',')[:2]): i[:-1].split(',') for i in open('output_20170503.csv')}` to `new = {"".join(i.split(',')[:1]): i[:-1].split(',') for i in open('output_20170503.csv')}` ?

Comment: Actually, `"".join(i.split(',')[:2])` is just the key of the dict, I make this dict to update the `base.csv` . The code iterates the file , `i[:-1].split(',')` split the line to a list (like `['1','John','45','Round','Meow']`). You can get the slicing of list see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation). You need to read the Python docs to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use `pandas` library which is excellent for data manipulation. you can read easily csv files and do [merge operation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html). Your solution might look like the following :

```
import pandas as pd

base_df = pd.read_csv('base.csv')
output_df = pd.read_csv('My output_20170503.csv')

output_df.update(base_df)

output_df.write_csv('My output_20170503.csv')
```

The missing values on output_df has now been updated with the one from base_df.